# Dynamic Data in Shopify Blog Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I want to write an API, i.e. hosted at www.api.mywebsite.com (not affiliated with Shopify) and then have a shopify blog post that queries that API and displays that data using javascript.

I know how to do the API potion, but can I and if so how do I do the second part where I use JS to query and display data?

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Add an App Proxy to your App. With that, you setup an end point to call in your App. On the blog page you can send an Ajax GET with an ID to your App, which can then get dynamic content ready for you to use. You can either format the response as Liquid or as JSON as two examples. Send back Liquid, and Shopify renders it for you. Send back JSON and you can stamp out your data in a template.

And best of all it is a secure callback to your App that you know came from Shopify, so you have no hassles or security problems. Look in your App for Extensions, and enable Online Store, where you can tinker with the Proxy.